# Select country & automatic generate phone code in Contact Form 7 - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 Plugin I need to changes on this form check detail below If any related plugin please suggest me Select Country and auto generate phone number in text box

Location: UAE (Select in dropdown)

Code: +971 (automated appear)

Can any one guide me how can i achieve

Answer (score 1):

There is a contact form addon plugin for Contact Form 7 named "Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7" , Just install it and configure it.

After the plugin installation, If you edit your CF7 form, you will see an additional tag called “Conditional fields Group”.

A detailed example of how to use the plugin can be found here: http://bdwm.be/wpcf7cf/how-to-set-up-conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7/